# How tu run GUI application inside docker without any real display?

Tags: python, docker, user-interface

I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline in docker(debian). One of the steps uses third party python app, which loads some GUI libraries at some point. If I run the same command on my system, no window will come up and no user interaction is needed. The app seems to be perfectly happy running in command line only.

However, if I try running it inside a docker container, i get this error

```
Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?
```

I tried(and failed) to set up the X display. But even If I did, it wouldn't help me, since the whole point of dockerizing the process is to run it on headless server.

Is there a way to somehow attach a fake display to the docker image, so that the app can load correctly? Or at least simulate the same situation on my local machine, so that I can step through the python code and find the offending bit?

Comment: Have you tried something like pyvirtualdisplay? https://pypi.org/project/PyVirtualDisplay/

Comment: The normal method would be using `xvfb` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

**Run inside docker and connect docker container to host display to get GUI output.**

Applications need to ask **Xserver** to display their GUI elements. And there's an authorization system designed for security, we'll discuss that later.

In our case, as containers use **host's hardware**, configuration of Xserver for Container is not needed. All we need is to **make our container able to talk with host Xserver**.

As I mentioned earlier, authorization is needed to contact Xserver, this authorization system is called **xauth**. xauth usually stores session cookies inside */home/username/.Xauthority* file(**usually but not always**).

- **check for the current cookies in use**

```
xauth list
```

output will look like this,

```
localhost.localdomain/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  99aaccf2d83177ddf581e2989ebbcea1
#ffff##:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  99aaccf2d83177ddf581e2989ebbcea1
```

- **in case the Xauthority is not located at the usual place, check which authority file is in use**

```
xauth
```

output will look something like this if standard file is not in use,

```
Using authority file /run/user/1000/xauth_Abcde
```

We need to supply these two things to our container,

- **MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1** - for now just think of this as a protocol or identifier. This is constant for every session.
- **99aaccf2d83177ddf581e2989ebbcea1** - this 32 letter key is the session key or whatever fancy name you want to give it. Key is unique for each session.

**Now to resolve issues related to display we need to do these five things,**

1. Create a .Xauthority file if not present already inside container
2. Add our session key and protocol to the .Xauthority file we created
3. Pass DISPLAY environment variable to container
4. Mount host Xserver socket(usually located at */tmp/.X11-unix*) to container
5. Set network type to *host*(required for display rendering)

These 5 steps will fix all issues related to display.

## Example

**The method works with any GUI app, this example demonstrates using firefox GUI.**

How those 5 steps are addressed here in chronological order:

1. Done inside Containerfile `RUN touch .Xauthority`
2. Both passed as environment variables

protocol set in Containerfile `ENV PROTOCOL=MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1`

session key passed as argument to `podman run` `--env KEY=$(xauth list | sed '2,$d'| tr -d '\n' | tail -c 32) \`(can't pass inside the container file as constant because it changes session to session)

and then added to authority file via `CMD xauth add ${HOST}:0 $PROTOCOL $KEY` from Containerfile

3. Passed as argument to `podman run` `--env DISPLAY \`
4. Passed as argument to `podman run` `--mount type=bind,source=/tmp/.X11-unix,target=/tmp/.X11-unix,readonly \`
5. Configured while building the image `podman build --network=host --tag guitest .`

### Containerfile

```
FROM debian:latest

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update && apt upgrade
RUN apt install --no-install-recommends --yes firefox-esr pipewire pipewire-alsa pipewire-pulse ffmpeg xauth

ENV PROTOCOL=MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1

ENV HOME /home/def
ENV USER def

RUN useradd --create-home --home-dir ${HOME} -G audio,video ${USER} && chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ${HOME}

WORKDIR ${HOME}
USER ${USER}

RUN touch .Xauthority

CMD xauth add ${HOST}:0 $PROTOCOL $KEY && firefox
```

### Build Command

```
podman build --network=host --tag guitest .
```

### Run Container using the image we built

```
podman run -it --rm --name guiapp \
--env DISPLAY \
--env KEY=$(xauth list | sed '2,$d'| tr -d '\n' | tail -c 32) \
--mount type=bind,source=/tmp/.X11-unix,target=/tmp/.X11-unix,readonly \
guitest
```

#### BINGO !

**Disclaimer:** Audio will not work, that needs some more work to be done.